# Strange error during build docker using heroku.yml

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to build and deploy app using new feature *heroku.yml* https://blog.heroku.com/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Build was successful but after pushed to registry I see error:

```
unsupported
=!= Build failed due to an error:
=!= push step: exit status 1
If this persists, please contact us at https://help.heroku.com/.
```

Source code of *heroku.yml* https://github.com/jincod/AspNetCoreDemoApp/blob/develop/heroku.yml

Comment: What is the content of your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: happened to me as well :(

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU https://github.com/jincod/AspNetCoreDemoApp/blob/develop/Dockerfile. Sorry for late answer

Answer (score 0):

Heroku only supports Linux images.
You cannot use `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpin`, as that's a windows image.

Comment: here alpine tag - it's linux image